# getPlatformIDs() returns -1001 even though nvidia.icd exists and contains 'libcuda.so'

Tags: c++, ubuntu, opencl, nvidia, dlopen

I have been playing around with OpenCL recently on my Ubuntu 12.04 machine.  When I call `cl::Platform::get`, I get an error code of -1001.  After some research, I have found that this happens when the c call `getPlatformIDs` fails to find a valid platform, and that this can happen when there are no .icd files in your /etc/OpenCL/vendors/ directory, or when the implementation(s) referenced by the file(s) cannot be opened with a call to `dlopen`.
I, however have tested all of these possibilities.  In /etc/OpenCL/vendors/, I found nvidia.icd, which contains the line 'libcuda.so'.  I then tried to call `dlopen` on this filename, and succeeded.  Yet, my program still returns an error code of -1001!  My nvidia drivers work well in all other respects, and I am able to compile the program.  What could possibly be wrong?

Zistack

EDIT: Extra info: I am using the nvidia-current-dev drivers.  I am running an nvidia GeForce GT 540M.

EDIT: I found something interesting just recently:  [Here](http://www.khronos.org/registry/cl/extensions/khr/cl_khr_icd.txt) is the spec from Khronos on the icd loader.  It says:

> Upon successfully loading a Vendor ICD's library, the 
>   ICD Loader queries the following functions from the library:
>   clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR, clGetPlatformInfo, and 
>   clGetExtensionFunctionAddress.  If any of these functions
>   are not present then the ICD Loader will close and ignore 
>   the library.

And [here](http://www.nvnews.net/vbulletin/showthread.php?t=159051) is a post from someone implementing an icd loader trying to load the nvidia platform.  It says:

> I can get clGetExtensionFunctionAddress and clGetPlatformInfo
>   from libcuda.so using dlsym(), and I can then use
>   clGetExtensionFunctionAddress to retrieve clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR.

In my experementation, I was able to query only 2 out of 3 functions successfully - `clGetPlatformInfo`, and `clGetExtensionFunctionAddress`.  The other one failed, as the forum post suggests it should: the author goes on to say that they use `clGetExtensionFunctionAddress` to retrieve `clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR`.  If the ICD loader implemented by Khronos follows the spec word for word, then it would make sense that it would fail, as the query for `clIcdGetPlatformIDsKHR` would fail, and the library would be ignored.  Given that, it seems that the nvidia implementation does not seem to fully implement the spec, unless there is another, newer version that I am unaware of.  Yet other people manage to get OpenCL working just fine on their nvidia platforms.  Am I missing something?

Comment: Have you tried programs like clinfo (http://sourceforge.net/projects/clinfo/) ? Do they fail as well?

Comment: @ananthonline I have tried a couple of examples from enja.org, and they all yield the same error.

Comment: how about cuda's deviceQuery?

Comment: @ardiyu07: I am actually having trouble compiling that.  I'm getting an undefined reference to 'cuDeviceGetAttribute' error.  If I get it working, I'll let you know.

Comment: make sure your include path and lib path are pointing to the right library..

Comment: @ardiyu07: Right now I'm pointing the linker to /usr/lib/nvidia-current/libcuda.so for -lcuda.  Unfortunately, it seems that this library is the source of all of my problems, but I cannot figure out why, unless this isn't the right library...

Comment: Check the symbolic link of your libcuda.so, maybe it's pointing to a blank library. You can use the 'ls -l' command to check symbolic links destination.

Comment: @ardiyu07: It's pointing to libcuda.so.295.40, which is definitely not blank, as I have successfully queried clGetPlatformInfo, clGetExtensionFunctionAddress, and even cuDeviceGetAttribute.  At this point the question is: why does the linker fail to find these symbols, yet I succeed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out, the output of this command says it all:

```
lspci | grep VGA
00:02.0 VGA compatible controller: Intel Corporation 2nd Generation Core Processor Family Integrated Graphics Controller (rev 09)
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GF108 [GeForce GT 540M] (rev ff)
```

I have optimus technology, and therefore my system uses the Intel VGA controller by default.  As such, the nvidia platform is invalid because there is no hardware attached to the software from my program's point of view.  Unfortunately there is no easy way to just tell the operating system to ignore the Intel chip and just use the nvidia one, and nvidia doesn't feel like supporting optimus under linux, so there are no drivers for this setup.  However, installing bumblebee and running my program with `optirun` works like a charm.

Comment: I used nvidias drivers for cuda and then http://bumblebee-project.org/install.html and optirun exe args, http://www.webupd8.org/2012/11/primus-better-performance-and-less.html