# OpenCL Example Failing

Tags: c, opencl

I'm trying to go through the example at the below webpage:
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/OpenCL-Guide/blob/main/chapters/getting_started_linux.md

I know this example is for Ubuntu, but I used RHEL 8 and installed opencl-headers and ocl-icd-devel packages so it compiled fine, but I got

[19:25]ec2-user@ec2lm-0e2cec915$ ./HelloOpenCL

clGetPlatformIDs(-1001)

Anyone know what this code means? Could it be because I'm missing other drivers for openCL to interact with my CPU or GPU?

Comment: If you have an `NVIDIA` GPU you can try to install the [latest nvidia_modprobe package](https://github.com/NVIDIA/yum-packaging-nvidia-modprobe/). If this doesn't help you can check [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11926710/18667225]).

Comment: I'm trying to get nvidia-driver approved for install. Will I still need modprobe?